# How can I change the randered widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

Hello I want to change my randered widget on click but I can not mnage to do it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: BackButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  FONCİON
                });
              },
            ),
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text('demo'),
            backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 77, 222, 255),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class secondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const secondPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

I want to change rendered widget to secondpage on click how can I do it

I want to change rendered widget on click

Comment: You should check out "routing in flutter".

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation

In your example you can do this (I have changed `secondPage` to `SecondPage`):

```dart
  leading: BackButton(
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondPage()));
    },
  ),
```

Also it might me helpful to use router package like [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route), [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router), [routemaster](https://pub.dev/packages/routemaster), etc.